# Replace live() with on()

Tags: jquery

From the documentation

```
$(selector).live(events, data, handler);                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, data, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, data, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1

This works, for static elements and dynamically loaded elements:

```
$("input").live("change", function () { alert("hello"); });
```

This doesn't work, not even for static elements:

```
$("document").on("change", "input", function () { alert("hello"); });
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Write it like

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function () { alert("hello"); });
```

You can replace `document` with any `closer parent element` which will always exist in `DOM` for better performance. Like

```
$('#closest_static_container_id').on("change", "input", function () { 
     alert("hello"); 
});
```

if you use `$("document")` jQuery will search for a `node/tag` named as `document` like `<document>` and wont find anything as [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document) is actually an `object`.

But you could use `$("body")` as `body` is a node/element of `DOM`.

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
$("document").on(...)
```

To:

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function () { alert("hello"); });
```

[`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document) is an object (a property of `window`), not a node type.

```
$("document").on(...)
```

Is looking for `<document>` elements in the `document` object, like:

```
<document>
```

And as you probably got by  now, there is none...

Anyway the best practice with `on` is to use the closest static element to the dynamic added elements Something like:

```
<div id='container-div-id'>
    <input />  ... this will be added later.
</div>

$('#container-div-id').on("change", "input", function () {
     alert("hello"); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

`document` is an object and you are using it as a string. So `jQuery` will try to use it as a css selector and it will not find anything to attach the event handler.

Try this.

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function () { alert("hello"); });
```